# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.age' in 'field list'

Tags: database

we are getting this error in the image

under Catalog > Manage > Attributes.

[image]

we imported this table : http://pastebin.com/1qKW9g8E

Comment: rebuild your indexes

Comment: sorry for delayed reply, i done re indexing, it took long time. now its working, please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rebuild your indexes. most probably the "age" attribute that you just added to the eav_attribute table is not present in the flat table.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right., its not there under Catalog > Manage attributes.  the problem is still not solved.

Comment: so, now is i have to delete that age attribute again from database and i have to follow correctly what you said yesterday.